# Triviality of the Hodge bundle for a special family of semistable curves

Tags: algebraic-curves, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let g,h be positive integers. Let E be an elliptic curve, C be a genus h curve, and D be a genus g-h-1 curve. Let c,d,e be points on (resp.) C,D, and E.

Let f:CC --> E-e be the family whose fiber over a point e' is the curve obtained by glueing C to E together at the points c and e and D to E at the points d and e'.

> Question: what is the pushforward f<sub>*</sub> ω<sub>f</sub>
>   ?

It should be trivial, and David Speyer's answer to my question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2107/question-about-a-family-of-semistable-curves/2145#2145) should answer this question, but I (and a few others I asked earlier) couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under (the extension of) Torrelli this curves maps to one point in Ag. On the other hand the hodge class on Mg minus D0 is a pullback (under the extension of Torelli) of the hodge class on Ag.

Comment: Right. Thanks, I think David Speyer's previous answer was a red herring.